# Yii functional testing

Tags: yii, functional-testing

I try to do functional test like to example into The Definitive Guide to Yii.

This is my fixture into tbl_showcase.php:

```
return array(
    'sample1'=>array(
        'title'=>'Welcome',
        'content'=>'A main page test',
        'row_type'=>1,
    ),
    'sample2'=>array(
        'title'=>'About',
        'content'=>'An about page test',
        'row_type'=>2,
    ),
);
```

This is my test class:

```
class ShowcaseTest extends WebTestCase
{
    public $fixtures = array('showcase'=>'Showcase');

    public function testIndex()
    {
        $this->open('/');

        $this->assertTextPresent($this->showcase['sample1']['title']);
        $this->assertTextPresent('Welcome');

        $this->assertTextPresent($this->showcase['sample1']['content']);
        $this->assertTextPresent('A main page test');
    }
}
```

I start test

```
phpunit functional/ShowcaseTest.php
```

and get next error:

```
Time: 8 seconds, Memory: 6.25Mb

There was 1 error:

1) ShowcaseTest::testIndex
Exception: Unknown property 'name' for class 'ShowcaseTest'.

/home/myfolder/web/yii/framework/test/CWebTestCase.php:48

FAILURES!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 0, Errors: 1.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get around it by explicitly giving `name` property to ShowcaseTest class, like that:

```
public $fixtures = array('showcase'=>'Showcase');
public $name = 'Something Meaningful';
```

Or look into fixtures file itself, where properties are defined.

Comment: I'm beginner in Yii. Please little more about "explicitly giving name property to ShowcaseTest class". Show code example, please, if it possible. I can speak to russian and ukrainian.

Comment: I don't understand what is the "name" property. Whose is the name?

Comment: The test infrastructure depends on the name property of the testing class, but the class which you define somehow doesn't have it - unless you assign the property manually. The value of this property is actually not relevant, it seems.

Comment: Я понял не все. Но общий смысл понятен. Где можно детально прочитать об этом?

Comment: Please write in english, makes it impossible for most people to understand or respond otherwise.